# Why do artilects don't interfere much in the conflicts of lower order sapients and vice versa?

Tags: space, politics, artificial-intelligence, trans-humanism, game-theory

In my universe there are beeing orders of magnitudes more intellegent and powerful than baseline humans and their transhuman counterparts. There exist a number of levels of mental power. These are: animal, human, enhanced human, artilect, planet scale artilect, solar scale artilect. This is only a rough classification system, its borders are fuzzy, but there are definitive and nearly insurmountable barriers between each of the levels.

Conflicts are still fought in the setting. The setting has a strict no FTL rule and thus the largest galactic empires never exceed a few hundred solar systems. Most systems are their own political microcosms. Technology is generally quite hard scifi, rockets, ralguns and raycannons. High level artilects have access to monopole tech and space time manipulation. Sometimes these technologies are gifted to lower beeings, but even if the devices aren't filled with anti tampering devices, reverse engeneering is violently discouraged.

My question is **why conflicts tend to stay on the same or at least near levels of development?** Why is no one generally neutron bombing natives? Spillover, escalation and non-obvious intentions do happen, but aren't the norm.

This situation has held for millions of years since the first artilect war in the solar system, where the anti-human artilects (skynets and mad hatters) where defeated by the prohuman faction (libertarians and caretaker gods).

Comment: When's the last time you interfered in the conflict between the two ant-hills in your front yard? If you bother to intervene at all, you're probably spraying them both with raid. Or just stomping on them and never noticing. I don't know what the ants would need to do to attract my attention, but if it ever gets so bad that they actually hurt anything I care about, swift and brutal genocide is a trivial matter for me and that's at the very bottom of the spectrum of escalation that I'm capable of. It goes up from there.

Comment: Do humans and artillects coexist in the same space? When humans use nukes, are artillects affected, or those are no more than bird droppings are to humans?

Comment: @Alexander Sometimes bird droppings irritate humans too. But birds are on the wing and gone by the time the human might think to retaliate. I daresay that humans are flitting through 12-dimensional space in a direction and at a speed that not-quite-gods couldn't follow. More likely, nukes are less than pigeon shit though.

Comment: RE: "Spillover isn't the norm": I'm not sure I believe that. I keep thinking of the "no man's land" iin WWI, and the effects it must have had on the local wildlife.

Comment: Is this setting Orion's Arm? https://www.orionsarm.com/

Comment: @nick012000 I do love Orion's Arm and consider it a major source of inspiration. So the setting is close to it, but there are other sources of inspiration. Alistair Reynolds, especially "House of Suns", Warhammer 40k and other Scifi series were also relevant. The central element is a very diverse universe where humans and their advanced decents existed for millions of years in a world without non-human-decendent aliens and FTL.

Comment: @MJ713 I don't consider collateral damage to be spillover. If an architect kills another artilects pet civilisation(s) while performing a relativistic attack against eir rival, it isn't spillover. If eir civilisations start fighting, that would be spillover.

Comment: @Alexander Yes and no. Many higher order artilects exist primarily in higher or pocket dimensions. However, support architecture is required to keep them connected. It isn't really provable if a purely higher dimensional AI can exist, because it is a rather phylosophical question if giving up all support infrastructure in real space is a way to ascend to somewhere or an eleborate way of committing suicide. The support infrastructure is wounderable to a well placed nuke.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight "No FTL" means that archilects' support is limited to a single planet, so planet-wide nuclear war should be of a real concern to them.

Comment: @Alexander System scale events/wars are the real issue. While most artilects do have a singe central location, subroutines, loyal agents and copies (be that simple gamma proxies, beta copies who are aware and happy of their nature and purpose, or even alpha copies which may either diverge or are kept synchronous by constant mutual updates) are an option to extend one's sphere of influence. In extreme cases this can allow an artilect to influence hundreds of systems over dozens of lightyears.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight lack of FTL makes multiplanetary artillect's thinking glacially slow. It may me immeasurable smarter than humans, but humans will be quick fleas whose actions it won't be able to track in real time.

Answer (score 13):

Isn't this what we do in our real world?

Insects, fishes, wolves, dogs and a lot of other animals fight on a daily base, without us taking part in the fight.

Just the other day I was seeing footage of two monkey groups fighting in the street of a city in Asia, with the only human intervention being filming the whole stuff to share it on social media.

If I am a transhuman being spanning an entire solar system, why should I bother with those meat-ware beings living on a single body of that system?

Everybody pick their battles and put energies where it's worth.

Comment: Or film the nuclear exchange on a body of the solar system in ultra-hyper-3D-HD for YouExperience, the transhuman social media site, with the title "Things Only Former 21st Century Human Intelligences Will Remember, LOL".

Comment: We regularly push animals out of their territory for our own benefits because we like having more land.

Answer (score 2):

Each artilect level makes he intelligence level below them fighting for sport. It's their equivalent of cockfighting. Artilects of the same level might even settle differences among themselves via <strike>pokémon</strike> civilization battles, e.g.: my humans vs your humans, whomever wins also gets a ceremonial badge.

Answer (score 1):

### The 'scarcity' problem has largely been solved/eliminated in high level trans humanist cultures. And not in lower level ones.

High end civilizations have effectively unlimited access to energy and information. Since anything they desire can be copied or exchanged they have no interest in competing over resources unlike lower end civilizations. So they don't. Except perhaps on areas of philosophy or 'cultural ideals' and since any war fought between two such powers over ideological issues would most likely be fatal to both sides they reach/negotiate 'accords' on how to interact with each other and importantly 'lesser' cultures.

It also follows that highly aggressive/militarist young cultures will (usually) eliminate themselves from the gene pool over time as they and other civilizations advance up the technological step latter. Large, violently aggressive advanced cultures would be extremely rare. (If only because their futures are so 'binary' i.e. Attack someone else and win - you expand. Attack someone else and lose - get destroyed/disarmed/reorganized by the victor.)

This also means the 'children' are allowed to fight each other. A least until such time as they develop a level of technology approaching that of the advanced cultures when they are introduced to the 'accords' and the potential consequences of breaking them. And of course by then most of the really aggressive ones are toast already and the rest are finding less and less reason to compete over resources anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Gravity Wells are for Suckers**

Any space-spanning culture rapidly outgrows living on planets. It's far too costly to keep launching out of them because that means lugging around chemical boosters that are rarely useful.

With the spacetime tech available, grabbing and mining space rocks is routine and well understood. Ditto for comets for water. Space habitats and the automation that build and maintain them are also thoroughly commoditized tech. This is an era of plenty for the basic material goods so long as you don't insist on living planet-side.

Likewise, if you don't care about planets, there's a LOT of choices for star systems to colonize. There's conflict, but only when special circumstances such as rare elements or exploitable high-energy environments are found.

Given this, why go to the chaos, expense and risk of conflict? Just move on to another location if your first choice is already occupied. The more advanced you are, the more off-putting the chaos of conflict is. Intelligent self interest based cooperation is the norm.

Answer (score 0):

The essential problem with this is that higher life forms are gonna want, for hard sci fi reasons, to take the land of the lower beings? As such, you need some major inhibitors to prevent different levels of beings interfering.

### Higher level treaties.

The highest tiers of beings, solar scale artilect, normally have treaties with each other over what territory they control or manage or influence. While they will allow conflict between tiers of beings, if higher level beings attempt to topple the situation they'll intervene.

The factions are pro human, so they oppose whole sale human destruction.

### Resource segregation.

The highest levels of beings use stars for power, and don't really need planet level resources. Those below are allotted particular resources to fight over.

Planet Scale artilect. Gas giants.
Artilects. Uninhabitable terrestial planets.
Enhanced humans. Moons and free floating asteroids.
Humans. Habitable planets, in urban areas.
Animals. Nature areas.

Trade for resources would be common, but contesting the territory of lower beings is seen as bad, and may attract intervention from the higher ups.